Karate UI Automation code for a button not working
I am trying to write code for click of a button. Text on the button says "CANCEL". I tried with xpath, * click("CANCEL")/ * click("{}CANCEL")/* click("{^}CANCEL"). Nothing seems to be working. Could you please help.
Code for the button is as below.
 Cancel  

 Cancel  

Try using mouse() instead.
* mouse(<locator>).click()

Try to use a CSS locator, if {}CANCEL does not work.
